# Error al agrupar los registros duplicados con group by

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

Tengo una consulta la cual trae información de los alumnos, pero resulta que algunos están duplicados entonces pensé en agruparlos por la matricula (PEOPLE_ID) pero cuando coloco el group by me marca el siguiente error.

¿Podrían ayudarme a saber porque me esta mandando ese error?

> Consulta sin group by

```
$this->db_sqlserver->select('p.PEOPLE_ID AS matricula, p.FIRST_NAME, p.MIDDLE_NAME, p.LAST_NAME AS a_paterno, p.Last_Name_Prefix AS a_materno, e.EmailType, e.Email AS email_institucional, a.ENROLL_SEPARATION AS estatus');        
$this->db_sqlserver->from('PEOPLE AS p');
$this->db_sqlserver->join('PEOPLETYPE AS pt', 'pt.PEOPLE_ID = p.PEOPLE_ID');
$this->db_sqlserver->join('EmailAddress AS e', 'e.PeopleOrgId = p.PEOPLE_ID');
$this->db_sqlserver->join('ACADEMIC AS a', 'a.PEOPLE_ID = p.PEOPLE_ID');
$this->db_sqlserver->where('pt.PEOPLE_TYPE', 'STUD');
$this->db_sqlserver->where('a.ACADEMIC_YEAR', date("Y"));
$this->db_sqlserver->where('a.ACADEMIC_TERM', "1");
$this->db_sqlserver->where('e.EmailType', 'INST');
$this->db_sqlserver->limit(50);  

$query = $this->db_sqlserver->get()->result();

return $query;
```

> Resultado (usuarios duplicados)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Consulta con group by

```
$this->db_sqlserver->select('p.PEOPLE_ID AS matricula, p.FIRST_NAME, p.MIDDLE_NAME, p.LAST_NAME AS a_paterno, p.Last_Name_Prefix AS a_materno, e.EmailType, e.Email AS email_institucional, a.ENROLL_SEPARATION AS estatus');        
$this->db_sqlserver->from('PEOPLE AS p');
$this->db_sqlserver->join('PEOPLETYPE AS pt', 'pt.PEOPLE_ID = p.PEOPLE_ID');
$this->db_sqlserver->join('EmailAddress AS e', 'e.PeopleOrgId = p.PEOPLE_ID');
$this->db_sqlserver->join('ACADEMIC AS a', 'a.PEOPLE_ID = p.PEOPLE_ID');
$this->db_sqlserver->where('pt.PEOPLE_TYPE', 'STUD');
$this->db_sqlserver->where('a.ACADEMIC_YEAR', date("Y"));
$this->db_sqlserver->where('a.ACADEMIC_TERM', "1");
$this->db_sqlserver->where('e.EmailType', 'INST');
$this->db_sqlserver->group_by('p.PEOPLE_ID');
$this->db_sqlserver->limit(50);  

$query = $this->db_sqlserver->get()->result();

return $query;
```

> Resultado (error)

```
Error Number: 42000/8120

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'PEOPLE.FIRST_NAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

SELECT "p"."PEOPLE_ID" AS "matricula", "p"."FIRST_NAME", "p"."MIDDLE_NAME", "p"."LAST_NAME" AS "a_paterno", "p"."Last_Name_Prefix" AS "a_materno", "e"."EmailType", "e"."Email" AS "email_institucional", "a"."ENROLL_SEPARATION" AS "estatus" FROM "PEOPLE" AS "p" JOIN "PEOPLETYPE" AS "pt" ON "pt"."PEOPLE_ID" = "p"."PEOPLE_ID" JOIN "EmailAddress" AS "e" ON "e"."PeopleOrgId" = "p"."PEOPLE_ID" JOIN "ACADEMIC" AS "a" ON "a"."PEOPLE_ID" = "p"."PEOPLE_ID" WHERE "pt"."PEOPLE_TYPE" = 'STUD' AND "a"."ACADEMIC_YEAR" = '2020' AND "a"."ACADEMIC_TERM" = '1' AND "e"."EmailType" = 'INST' GROUP BY "p"."PEOPLE_ID" ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/IntranetUCQ/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Saludos y bonito viernes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se agrupa por una columna se debe aplicar una función de agregación al resto de columnas.

```
SELECT p.people_id AS matricula, -- columna agrupada
       Max(p.first_name), -- seleccionar el MAX() de ese grupo
       Max(p.last_name) as a_paterno -- seleccionar el MAX() de ese grupo
FROM   people AS p 
GROUP  BY people_id
```

Todas las columnas del `select` que no son parte del `group by` deben estar en una función de agregación.

**Forma 2**

Se puede usar `distinct` para quitar los duplicados.

```
SELECT distinct p.people_id AS matricula, 
           p.first_name, 
           p.middle_name
    FROM   people AS p
```

Comment: entonces le pongo un max() a cada uno de los datos que quiero traer en la consulta?

Comment: Sí, eso sería usado  `group by` pero también se puede usar `distinct ` actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: les estoy poniendo el max a los datos que quiero traer, pero tengo una duda. el max a los datos que tienen alias ejemplo p.LAST_NAME AS a_paterno, se encierra todo el dado asi max(p.LAST_NAME AS a_paterno) o solo el alias asi p.LAST_NAME AS max(a_paterno)?

Comment: `MAX(p.LAST_NAME) as a_paterno` Se encierra la columna el alias queda afuera.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!  @Lobos